# Prove that an edge in planar graph cannot belong to three faces using the Jordan curve theorem

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Given a planar drawing $D$ of a graph $G$, how can I prove that an edge cannot belong to three faces in the drawing $D$? I am looking for a proof that

1. uses the Jordan curve theorem, and
2. does not assume $D$ is a straight line drawing of $G$.

This question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425840/why-an-edge-does-not-belong-to-three-faces), and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3425850/460691) suggests that the Jordan curve theorem can be used to give a proof. [Another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3441868/460691) uses the Jordan curve theorem, but assumes that the edges of $G$ are drawn as line segments in $D$.